# Which can be a flexible data structure for constructing two dimensional table with complex row indices?

Tags: python, data-structures

I would like to construct a two dimensional table in python where rows has to be  indexed by **tuples**, which contains ***list, list of lists, integers*** whereas the columns are indexed by integers. The entries in table are integers.

In this scenario, which data structure will fit for my requirement? Will it be list or dictionary or any other?

The only operations I use to perform on the table are accessing and updating.

Comment: Tuples that contain lists aren't hashable, so that could be a problem. Are you flexible on that requirement?

Comment: @wjandrea unfortunately, the requirement is mandatory for me. Else, I need to modify at several places, which I don't want to do now.

Comment: So then what should happen if you have duplicate indices? Should both be updated, or only the first occurence?

Comment: @wjandrea There are no duplicates here

Comment: It is impossible to fulfill **exactly** your requirements. Python lists aren't hashable, thus cannot be used as indices. There are many alternatives and solutions, but without a bit more context on what you are doing, it's hard to make a meaningful suggestion.